# Hovering over a deleted chat message makes it look like you can still star it

Tags: bug, chat-stars

When you hover over deleted chat messages, it seems possible to star the message. As expected, clicking the star does not have any effect, but it seems better not to display the star at all.

[image]

Comment: The other icon displayed there is the "spam, inappropriate, offensive" flag. IIRC, you also can't flag deleted messages. So, if one is going to be "fixed", the other might as well be fixed at the same time. OTOH, I've got to admit that I'm fairly "meh" on this one being fixed, as it doesn't seem to be causing any inappropriate operation and not all that much confusion.

Comment: Yeah, that one *may* be useful if there's a troll posting offensive messages and deleting them quickly, but only if it's working, that's right.

Comment: I'd be more interested in having the "flag for moderator" flag (available from the message's popup) enabled on deleted messages than the spam flag. The spam flag is mostly a "delete this message now" flag and doesn't guarantee that the message is seen by a moderator. It serves a good purpose, but that purpose is really over once the message is deleted.